# Excel opens data source when I refresh Access connection

Tags: excel, ms-access, database-connection

I have 3 Excel files (A, B an C). Files A and B are linked tables in Access data base. In file C I use some queries from Access as external data source. The problem is, that when somebody has file A (or B) opened for editing, and i'm refreshing file C, Excel opens file A (or B) in Read-Only mode. Problem doesn't show when file A (or B) isn't being edited.

Any ideas how can i menage this problem (I don't want Excel to open file A or B when i refresh file C)